# Unable to add price during adding product 2.0.2

Tags: price, magento2.2, frontend, backend, special-price

Here is my partial code

```
    $productObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $totalAdded ++;
        $productObj->setName($value->product_name) // Use default        
        // ->setStoreId(39)
           ->setPrice(100.99) 
            // price in form 100.99

        ->setAttributeSetId(9) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
        ->setStatus($var_val->status)
        ->setVisibility(4)
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->setWebsiteIds(array($websiteId))
        ->setDescription($value->description)

        //->setSpecialPrice($var_val->min_price) //special price in form 11.22
        ->setSku($var_val->sku."-".$var_val->variant_id) //SKU        
      ->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
            'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
            'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'max_sale_qty'=>2, 
             //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
            'qty' => $var_val->quantity //qty
        ))       

        ->setColor($var_val->color)
        ->setWeight($var_val->weight);
```

after adding product price is not getting stored in backend and showing 0 in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `setFinalPrice(100.99)` instead of `setPrice(100.99)`.

I hope this will help you.